# Ошибка префикса L перед строкой

Tags: c++

Использую OLE Automation. Пытаюсь получить свойство-документ у объекта верхнего уровня Application.

```
OLECHAR* name = L"Document";
hr = pIDispatch->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &name, 1, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, &dispIDDocument);
```

Выпадает ошибка на букву L в первой строке `"Значение типа "const wchar_t*" нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа "OLECHAR *"`

Знаю, что проблема в настройках проекта, но изменение свойства "Набор символов" ничего не даёт

Comment: Тогда эту переменную не принимает функция GetIDsOfNames

Comment: Пробовал это всё, пишет что name не совместим с параметром LPOLESTR *

Comment: Нашел документацию. Судя по ней, то у Вас всё верно. Я бы попробовал написать так: `const OLECHAR* name = OLESTR("Document");` или так `OLECHAR name[] =  OLESTR("Document");`

Comment: нет, это не помогает. я считаю, что проблема в настройках проекта.